# undefiend value in array of objects Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

im trying to make an array with objects but while looping i get as a result the first  83 objects as undefiend and only the last 4 with correct data. I tried to refactor the code several times but i dont seem to find a solution.

[This is the console log result i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPMDO.jpg)

[This is the network response i get from the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eZwU.jpg)

```
<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        allSales(){
            var i, sales=[], x, y
            for (i = 0; i <= this.salesLists.length; i++) {
                sales[i] = {
                    x:this.date(i+1),
                    y:this.amount(i+1),
                    status:this.status(i+1),
                }
            }
            console.log(sales);// first 83 objects undefined
            return sales
        },
        salesLists() {
            this.$store.state.sale.sales
        },
    },
    methods:{
        date(id) {
            return this.salesLists.filter(sale => sale.id === id).map(sale => new Date(sale.updated_at).toISOString().slice(0,10))[0];
        },
        amount(id) {
            return this.salesLists.filter(sale => sale.id === id).map(sale => sale.amount)[0];
        },
        status(id) {
            return this.salesLists.filter(sale => sale.id === id).map(sale => sale.status)[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `map` on the object returned by `filter` in your methods. Why are you doing this?

Comment: In your `allSales()` computed property, you aren't actually doing anything with the data contained in `salesLists`, you're simply using its length. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your second screenshot, I see that your `salesLists` has elements with `id`s greater than `87`, or the length of the `salesLists` array. This is an issue, because in your `for` loop you are assuming that every element of the array has an `id` that is `>= 1` and `<= salesLists.length`.

Because this is not the case, there are several iterations of the loop where your `date`, `amount`, and `status` methods return `undefined`.

I would recommend that you transform the `salesLists` array directly in the computed method in a single call to `map`. It might look something like this:

```
allSales(){
  return salesLists.map(sale => {
    return {
      x: new Date(sale.updated_at).toISOString().slice(0,10),
      y: sale.amount,
      status: sale.status
    }
  })
},
```